# Remove datestamp (watermark) from videos

Tags: video, video-editor, kdenlive

I accidentally enabled a datestamp "feature" on my camera and now all my videos have the date embedded.

What's the best way to remove those datestamps?

I'm editing a compilation of the videos with kdenlive, so I would only need to remove the datestamp from the parts of the videos I'm using or the final compilation, whatever gives best results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) (download a static build for your operating system) and its [`delogo`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo) filter, which will try to cover up a logo or watermark by interpolating neighboring pixels.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=100:y=100:w=150:h=20" output.mp4
```

Here, `x` and `y` specify the top left coordinates of the “masking” rectangle, and `w`/`h` specify its size. You can add the `show=1` option to help locate that rectangle.

If you want to play with the filter values, you can use `ffplay` to directly show the result:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i "movie=input.mp4,delogo=x=100:y=100:w=150:h=20:show=1"
```